# Подключение своей библиотеки в jupyter

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

Собственно проблема такая, я создаю проект в pycharm professional в режиме scientific. Pycharm создает мне директорию notebooks. В самом проекте у меня есть директория (python package)  где у меня лежат мои библиотеки. Она находится на одном уровне с директорией notebooks.
Вопрос, как мне из ноутбука подгрузить мои библиотеки...

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось просто

```
sys.path.append('..')
```